# Borrow computational power from machines around me

Tags: computational-chemistry, hpc

I'm a computational chemist working with little computational power and dealing with increasingly demanding chemical systems. My work machines are part of a big network (mixed with windows and linux) and I was asking myself: is it possible to "borrow" computational power from machines around me (with permission from my department, of course)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [HTCondor](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/) that is designed exactly to "steal" cpu cycles from remote machines. It may be a little difficult to setup but I think this may be the best approach.

Answer (score 6):

You could install [BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/) on those machines.  When the computers become idle, the BOINC screensaver/client requests tasks from a server and computes them.  See [more information about it here](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/How_BOINC_works).  This is the [software used by a number of projects](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/projects.php) such as SETI@Home. [You can create your own project with BOINC](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/trac/wiki/CreateProjectCookbook) and then put your desktop machines to work.

Comment: I have read about BOINC, the problem is that is is fixed to some projects, isn't it? I mean, one can not change it to his own project, just to contribute with existing and pre-selected scientific projects.

Comment: I just added a link to a tutorial on how to create your own independent BOINC project.